# Rectangular box pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program to print a rectangular box pattern in python . But , the last character jumped to the right side of first line. The desired output and actual generated output is mentioned in the code comment . What's the fault in my code ?

```
for i in range(10):
    print("x",end="")

for j in range(2):
    print("x"+" "*9+"x")

for k in range(10):
    print("x",end="")

#desired output:       xxxxxxxxxxx            my output:   xxxxxxxxxxx        x
#                      x         x                         x         x
#                      x         x                         x         x
#                      xxxxxxxxxxx                         xxxxxxxxxx


input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, because the last `x` printed out in the first `for` loop doesn't print a newline (due to `end=""`).

If you want your desired output, you need to print a newline after the first `for` loop (by calling `print()`), and you also need to change the `range` to 11 for the first and last `for` loops.

```py
for i in range(11):
    print("x",end="")

print()

for j in range(2):
    print("x"+" "*9+"x")

for k in range(11):
    print("x",end="")
```

Output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
x         x
x         x
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Also, how about this more generalised approach:

```py
WIDTH = 11
HEIGHT = 4

for i in range(WIDTH):
    print("x", end="")

print()

for j in range(HEIGHT - 2):
    print("x" + " "*(WIDTH - 2) + "x")

for k in range(WIDTH):
    print("x", end="")
```

It doesn't account for small sizes, but it's more flexible than before.